# Differ b/w type=submit & type=button in javascript?

Tags: javascript

*I'm trying to apply error class to email label. When I press button, which type=submit. error class apply and page again refresh imidiately & error class doesn't apply. When I do same at type=button, error class apply correctly to email label..!  *

```
<script>
function check()
{

    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var password = document.getElementById("password");
    if(email.value=='')
    {
        alert("email");
        email.className = 'error';
    }
    else
    {
         alert("not");
    }

}

</script>

<form>
<table width="264" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="84"><label for="Email">Email:  </label></td>
    <td width="164"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="Password">Password:</label></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><!--<input type="submit" class="signin_me" value="Sign in" onclick="check();" />-->
    <input type="button" class="signin_me" value="Sign in" onclick="check();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: [Read some documentation.](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `submit` input, your click causes the HTML form to be submitted. Because your HTML form does not have `action` attribute, this submission simply causes the same page to be reloaded. Thus, you cannot see the modification that you have done to email's `className`  (because the page gets reloaded soon after you click the button).

If you use `button` input, your click does not cause the HTML form to be submitted. Thus, you can see the modification that you have done to email's `className`.

Comment: Then what You suggest? do I apply action="my_file_name" in form. but I apply this It's also not worked for me.

Comment: Of course it does not work, because if you add `action=something` the HTML form gets submitted. What you are looking for is HTML FORM validation. The idea is that when we click the button, we validate the inputs from the user. If everything is fine, then we submit the HTML form. Otherwise, we display the errors. There are many examples out there that explain this in more detail.

Comment: Hi..!
I'm trying to apply display none & block by using javascript & jquery with hyperlink
but It's creating a problem for me. 
I'm new in Js & jquery.
Do anyone who help me on Skype..???